# PHP Why two same value from two different string are not equal to each other

Tags: php

Why are these two strings not equal?
I tried to get the same name so I can create a file, however I cannot get two strings equal to each other, even though I think both strings have the same value.
I uploaded var_dump output
any idea how to fix it?

```
$selectCategory = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/database/');

$cat = explode('.',$category);

    print_r($cat);
    print_r($selectCategory);

    if($cat[0] == $selectCategory[2]){
        echo " true";
    }
    else{
        echo "no";
    }

output:
Array ( [0] => bus [1] => php ) 
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => bus [3] => fruit )
 no

This is var_dump output
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) " bus" [1]=> string(3) "php" } 
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "." [1]=> string(2) ".." [2]=> string(3) "bus" [3]=> string(5) "fruit" } 
no
```

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and show us the results.

Comment: I updated var_dump output, looks like bus has string(5) from $cat, any idea how to fix it ? thank you !

Comment: So in the first array, the 0 index has a space a both ends (not that it's 5 characters long), so the strings are not the same. Maybe consider using [trim](http://php.net/trim).

Comment: perfectly solved my question , thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the `var_dump` output the items you are comparing are different lengths.  There is a space and possibly a hidden character in the `$cat` one:

To trim all space and some other characters use this:

```
$cat = array_map('trim', $cat);
$selectCategory = array_map('trim', $selectCategory);
```